# If or case conditions in Spark SQL lag function to get last not null lag

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, window-functions

Need add some conditions in Spark SQL `lag` function.

There are IDs and dates in my data and I want to get the closest lag date which is not null.

Input:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| er1 | 2018-01-19 |
| er1 | null |
| er1 | 2018-02-10 |
| er2 | 2018-11-11 |
| er2 | null |
| er2 | null |
| er2 | null |

---

```sql
select id, date,
       lag(date) PARTITION BY id order by date as last_date
from mytable
```

| id | date | last_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| er1 | 2018-01-19 | null |
| er1 | null | 2018-01-19 |
| er1 | 2018-02-10 | null |
| er2 | 2018-11-11 | null |
| er2 | null | 2018-11-11 |
| er2 | null | null |
| er2 | null | null |

But I find out that there are null values in the date column, and actually I want the last null date as `last_date`, so the second parameter of lag function is undetermined. I am trying to add a column to specify the number of nulls in previous rows or drop the null rows and join it, but is there better solutions?

I want to get this:

| id | date | last_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| er1 | 2018-01-19 | null |
| er1 | null | 2018-01-19 |
| er1 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-01-19 |
| er2 | 2018-11-11 | null |
| er2 | null | 2018-11-11 |
| er2 | null | 2018-11-11 |
| er2 | null | 2018-11-11 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard `lag()` function has an `ignore nulls` option:

```
select Id, date,
       lag(date ignore nulls) over (PARTITION BY id order by date) as last_date
from mytable;
```

But not all databases support this.  You can emulate it with a subquery:

```
select Id, date,
       min(date) over (partition by id, grp order by date) as last_date
from (select t.*,
             count(date) over (partition by id order by date) as grp
      from mytable t
     ) t
```

Comment: _lag() function has an ignore nulls option_ - [not in Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#lag). [`last` has](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#last).

Comment: @user6910411 . . . Then you can use `last()`.  That is a bespoke Spark function.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a column with lagged value,
then use [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#last) with `isIgnoreNull` argument set to `true`.

```sql
SELECT id, order_col, date, 
       last(last_val, true) over (partition by id order by order_col) last_date
FROM (SELECT *, lag(date) over (partition by id order by order_col) last_val
      FROM mytable)
```

---

Test in PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('er1', 1, '2018-01-19'),
     ('er1', 2, None),
     ('er1', 3, '2018-02-10'),
     ('er2', 1, '2018-11-11'),
     ('er2', 2, None),
     ('er2', 3, None),
     ('er2', 4, None)],
    ['id', 'order_col', 'date']
)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")

spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT id, order_col, date, 
           last(last_val, true) over (partition by id order by order_col) last_date
    FROM (SELECT *, lag(date) over (partition by id order by order_col) last_val
          FROM mytable)
    """
).show()
# +---+---------+----------+----------+
# | id|order_col|      date| last_date|
# +---+---------+----------+----------+
# |er1|        1|2018-01-19|      null|
# |er1|        2|      null|2018-01-19|
# |er1|        3|2018-02-10|2018-01-19|
# |er2|        1|2018-11-11|      null|
# |er2|        2|      null|2018-11-11|
# |er2|        3|      null|2018-11-11|
# |er2|        4|      null|2018-11-11|
# +---+---------+----------+----------+
```

---

PySpark instead of SQL:

```py
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("order_col")
df = df.withColumn("last_val", F.lag("date").over(w))
df = df.select(
    "id", "order_col", "date",
    F.last("last_val", True).over(w).alias("last_date")
)
```